# What pokemon is this? (POKEMON GO)

Tags: pokemon-go

I was at my house and saw a pokemon. It looks rare. Really rare. But I've never caught one of its type. I don't know what it is. I wish I could post a picture but IDK if I can on this site. It had a bushy looking tail with a plated arm, Spiky almost. It had small ears with a big, bulky body. Here's what I saw:

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about [**Arcanine**](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Arcanine_(Pok%C3%A9mon))? As for how to post images here, read this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images

Comment: Definitely not a Arcanine. Let me post a image, 1 sec

Answer (score 5):

The Pokémon you are looking for is a [**Magmar**](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Magmar_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

[image: Magmar]

Comment: Ah hah! Thanks! I missed him, sadly. One last question: is he rare?

Comment: @Jerome. I don't play Pokémon Go, so I don't know if Magmars are rare, but going by gut-feeling (and their rarity in the main Pokémon series) I'd say they aren't very common.

Comment: @Jerome Magmars are very rare